# Does Asp.net 5 comes with OWIN out of the box or do we need install it?

Tags: owin, asp.net-core, katana

- Is Asp.net 5 pre-build with OWIN(Katana) package?
- We don't need to add the Microsoft.Owin dll package into Asp.net 5.
  Am I right?
- If we want to use OWIN then what's lacking in Asp.Net 5?

Thanks, 
Chandru

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Edit:** 
According to [this](http://www.asp.net/vnext/overview/aspnet-vnext/aspnet-5-overview) The new asp.net pipeline supports OWIN through OWIN adapter, [here](https://github.com/aspnet/Entropy/tree/dev/samples/Owin.IAppBuilderBridge) is an example of that, more info on how OWIN fit in with asp.net 5 [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2014/11/14/katana-asp-net-5-and-bridging-the-gap.aspx).

1. No, if you want to use it you need to add it to the pipeline through `Startup.cs`
2. No, You need to add the `Microsoft.AspNet.Owin` to use it.
3. You need to add middleware request pipeline, use Microsoft.AspNet.Owin

Comment: Thanks. Regarding 3point: Yes OWIN is used to decouple the web server to run our app(.net 4.5) so now it's already been integrated with new ASP.Net 5. Whether any OWIN interface is missed to invoke or integrate in ASP.net 5? Is there any advantage to install the OWIN  package in ASP.net 5 web app?

Comment: Oh Okay now I understand. Thanks for your clarification. Great!!

Comment: @Chandru It turned out I was wrong, sorry for that, I've edited the question with correct answer.

Answer (score 2):

No, Asp.Net 5 is not built on OWIN (there is no `IDictionary<string, object>` environment), but it does use similar concepts and there is an interop package available. See https://github.com/aspnet/HttpAbstractions/tree/dev/src/Microsoft.AspNet.Owin, https://github.com/aspnet/Entropy/tree/dev/samples/Owin.IAppBuilderBridge, http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2014/11/14/katana-asp-net-5-and-bridging-the-gap.aspx